# jQuery selector precedence when using pattern matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am creating a form that implements a bunch of similar elements. They are custom select boxes, created out of `<ul>`s.

Some of these elements are slightly different in the way I want the `mousedown` event to be handled though.

The way I have it set up currently is that, by appending `_custom_select` to the end of an elements class name, it will be treated as one of these special elements as far as CSS is concerned.

However, when the string `selections` is found inside a class name (that will coincidentally also end with `_custom_select` in order to apply the proper styling) I want to use a different `mousedown` event handler.

This is the relevant section of my event listener set up:

```
$('[class$="_custom_select"] li').mousedown(function(event){
    var opt= event.target;
    if(opt.className!='li_disabled' && event.which==1)
    {
        if(opt.className=='li_unselected'){
            opt.className= 'li_selected';
        }
        else{
            opt.className= 'li_unselected';
        }
        update_selections(opt.parentElement);       
    }
});

$('[class*="selections"]').mousedown(function(event){
    var opt=event.target;
    if(event.which==1){
        if(opt.className=='li_unselected'){
            opt.className= 'li_selected_2';
        }
        else{
            opt.className= 'li_unselected';
        }
    }
});
```

This code works, but notice how, in the second binding, I had to bind the event listener to the `ul` that holds the `li` that is actually being clicked.(The `ul` is the element whose class name matches the pattern) In the first one however, I can bind the event listener directly to the `li` elements contained within the `ul`.

If I change the second jQuery selector to `$('[class*="selections"] li')` the event listener is never bound to the corresponding `li`s.

What is causing this behavior?

I am aware that I can just check `event.target.tagName` to ensure the event is bubbling up from an `<li>`, but that is not what the question is about.

---

I originally thought it had something to do with precedence and that the listeners weren't being bound because the `li`s that would have matched the second selector already matched against the first selector.

However, after implementing logging and looking at the DOM I have determined that when I change the second selector to: `$('[class*="selections"] li')` ***neither*** event listener is bound to the `li`s that match the second selector.

Here is a link to a JS fiddle of the 'working version'. If you add `' li'` to the second selector and then try to click the `<li>`s in the box to the right, you will see that they no longer become green.

### jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/6sg6z33u/4/

Comment: Is requirement to _not_ call first `mousedown` event when second mousedown event occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks for posting the jsFiddle. This is an easy fix!

The elements in your second `li` are being added dynamically. When you bind to elements using the shortcut methods like `.click()` it **only binds to the elements on the page when it initially bound**

The fix: use the `.on()` method, which is the preferred method per jQuery foundation. This method allows for **live binding** meaning it will pick up on dynamic elements.

```
$('[class*="selections"]').on( 'mousedown', 'li', function(event) {
    var opt = event.target;
    if (event.which == 1) {
        if (opt.className == 'li_unselected') {
            opt.className = 'li_selected_2';
        } else {
            opt.className = 'li_unselected';
        }
    }
});
```